# windows phone 8 application - override phone call task

Tags: windows-phone-8, phone-call, windows-phone-8-sdk

I have windows phone 8 application, and i want to override that PhoneCallTask message:

Dial [**DisplayName**] at [**PhoneNumber**]?

Is there a way to do this in windows phone 8 SDK?
Any help appreciated.

Comment: What's your mean about override phone call task? Could you give me a simple sample?

Answer (score 0):

you can checkout this link and download code samples https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ChatterBox-VoIP-sample-app-b1e63b8b